# c# - print RichTextBox text with correct spacing

Tags: c#, printing, size, richtextbox

I am making a program that can write in Bengali (a virtual keyboard) or in English. Everything was perfect until I started programming the printing. The user should be able to select any text and change the font and color. Because every character could be different, I need to print character by character. Here is my code:

```
private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();
    doc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
    print.Document = doc;
    doc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc);
    if (print.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        doc.Print();
    }
}

private void printDoc(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
    float linesPerPage = 0;
    float yPosition = 0;
    int count = 0;
    float leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    float rightMargin = e.MarginBounds.Right;
    float topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
    string line = null;
    Font printFont = this.richTextBox1.Font;
    SolidBrush printBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    int charpos = 0;
    int xPosition = (int)leftMargin;

    linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

    while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
    {
        xPosition = (int)leftMargin;
        yPosition = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
        count++;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(charpos, 1);
            if ((xPosition + ((int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(richTextBox1.SelectedText, richTextBox1.SelectionFont).Width)) > rightMargin)
            {
                count++;
                if (!(count < linesPerPage))
                {
                    break;
                }
                xPosition = (int)leftMargin;
                yPosition = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
            }
            printBrush = new SolidBrush(richTextBox1.SelectionColor);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.SelectedText, richTextBox1.SelectionFont, printBrush, new PointF(xPosition, yPosition));
            xPosition += ((int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(richTextBox1.SelectedText, richTextBox1.SelectionFont).Width);
            charpos++;
        }
    }

    if (line != null)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
        printBrush.Dispose();
    }
}
```

However, when I get a print preview, it shows a space between each of the the characters:

[image: print preview]

I think this is because `e.Graphics.MeasureString()` is not giving me the tightest bounding box possible, or it's not giving me the exact width of the character as specified by the font. I'm quite new to C# Anyone know of a way to get the exact width of a character? It's been stumping me for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT. Finally. You need to use `e.Graphics.MeasureString()` after all. Just another overload of it. Use this:

```
e.Graphics.MeasureString(richTextBox1.SelectedText, richTextBox1.SelectionFont, new PointF(xPosition, yPosition), StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Width;
```

To remove the space you need to pass StringFormat.GenericTypographic. Hope it helps. (you can use my code for printing text with different color and text if you replace `e.Graphics.MeasureString(string, Font)` with the above).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) MSDN article:

> The (Graphics Class) MeasureString method is designed for use with individual string **and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string to allow for overhanging glyphs**

You can instead use   [TextRenderer.MeasureString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66.aspx) to get the precise font width.

Comment: Not working, I'm getting the same result. I just replaced all the places where I had `e.Graphics.MeasureString()` with `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` and it's not working. Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: In the Remarks section of the MSDN for `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` is said `The MeasureText method requires that the text is drawn on a single line.`